# Do HTML affect ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, wikipedia-api

I was making Wikipedia viewer, and I implemented Wikipedia title search ajax calls were working fine until I added forms tag around input & button tag.

```
  <form class="pure-form">
    <input type="text" id="txtff" class="pure-input-rounded" placeholder="Search for...">
    <button type="submit" class="pure-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
  </form>
```

My ajax code is:

```
$("button").click(function() {

  var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=allpages&aplimit=5&apfrom=Albert";

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(resp){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
    },
    error: function(err){
      console.log("ERR")
    }
  });
});
```

I was doing all this on codepen: http://codepen.io/theami_mj/pen/KMKPvZ

Comment: HTML dont affect ajax .

Comment: What is the error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the problem was with `form` submission with `submit` button type added. Just add one line of code i.e. `e.preventDefault()` to prevent default action of your button which is `submitting the form`, so that it would not submit the `form`

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=allpages&aplimit=5&apfrom=Manoj";

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(resp) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log("ERR")
    }
  });
});
```

## [`UPDATED FIDDLE`](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/zBYJxK)

Comment: This will work, too. But I think using the standard onsubmit callback is the more "standard" way to go.

Comment: Its upto developer's choice buddy.. :) They can choose whichever they are convenient with.. If OP does not want to change any code and stick to what he have now, then this one is good to choose.. @lipp

Comment: @lipp, `onsubmit` handler function has to be global and `globals` must be avoided..`jQuery` event binding is more recommended way..

Answer (score 2):

> Use `type='button'`, `type='submit'` will submit the form and page will be unloaded.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=allpages&aplimit=5&apfrom=Albert";
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(resp) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log("ERR")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="pure-form">
  <input type="text" id="txtff" class="pure-input-rounded" placeholder="Search for...">
  <button type="button" class="pure-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>Go!
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should attach you click handler / AJAX call to the form's onsubmit event handler:

```
<form class="pure-form" onsubmit="myAjaxCall">
  <input type="text" id="txtff" class="pure-input-rounded" placeholder="Search for...">
  <button type="submit" class="pure-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
</form>
```

This would be your script (just created a function called myAjaxCall instead of attaching a click event handler).

```
myAjaxCall = function() {
  var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=allpages&aplimit=5&apfrom=Albert";

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(resp){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
    },
    error: function(err){
      console.log("ERR")
    }
  });
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior. button with type submit will send the form. Try to just replace type="submit" with type="button".

Answer (score 1):

You should get rid of the form, or you should add

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

To your JS code, to prevent the default behaviour of the form.

Alternatively, you could move all the logic from your button click event here, too:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // your AJAX call here
    return false;
});
```